# "Call to undefined relationship [latest_posts]" error on getting N related models per parent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a `Category` and `Post` Model that have a `ManyToMany` relationships.

like this :

```
class Category extends Model
{
        public function posts ()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'category_post', 'cat_id', 'post_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }

}
```

And `Post` model like this :

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_post', 'post_id', 'cat_id');
    }

}
```

Now I want to fetch some categories with their **X** posts of each them.

I searched a lot and tried different solutions,until I found [this solution](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/).
According that solution first I added  `scopeNPerGroup` function to `Category` model and this new relation to that :

```
    public function latest_posts()
    {
        return $this->posts()->latest()->nPerGroup('cat_id', 3);
    }
```

But When I want to select some categories and fetch their limited posts like this :

```
Category::with('latest_posts')
        ->whereIn('cat_id', [1,2,3,4])
        ->get();
```

I got this error :

```
Call to undefined relationship [latest_posts] on model [App\Category].
```

In addition to I want to make a dynamically capability where can sent a `x` parameter that specify count related models that should be fetch.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in name, try

```
public function latestPosts()
{
    return $this->posts()->latest()->nPerGroup('cat_id', 3);
}

Category::with('latest_posts')
    ->whereIn('cat_id', [1,2,3,4])
    ->get();
```